# Tree java how to find a word

Tags: java, tree

I am trying to read a node that will find the longest word in a tree.

My method is `public static int word(Node d)`. So how would I have to find the length of that node? Would I just use the string that was made in the class? The class I would use initializes a boolean, String: theWord and children. Here is what I got:

```
int newWord = 0;
int word = d.theWord.length();
if (d.isWord) {
    if (word > newWord) {
        newWord = word;
        return longestWord((DTN) d.children);
    } else {
        return longestWord((DTN) d.children);
    }
}
return newWord;
```

Comment: frankly couldnt make out much from your question. can u put more light on whether you are using swing and give more details. the problem statement is very hazy

Comment: okay, so the method takes a node in the parameter, and I was wondering how to find the length of the node, and then how would I call the children??

Comment: So the children are in an array inside the node? Can you show the data structure for the node?

Comment: The children is a Map with a String and Node, so did I call that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there's a little more information. I'm still not at all clear on what's going on here, but here's another stab at what I think is basically what you might want:

```
String longestWord(Node d) {
  String result = d.theWord;
  for (Node c : d.children) {
     String w = longestWord(c);
     if (result.length < w.length) result = w;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This assumes d.children is some collection of `Node`s.

Comment: This function is using both loops and recursion; for what you are doing you only need to use one of those two methods.

Comment: @R - not true.  He is working on the assumption that each node has a list or array of child nodes; i.e. it is an N-ary tree not a binary tree.  In this case, you have to iterate over the children, and then recurse for each one ... like he is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear, but the method is an int. Also, I don't know if calling theWord, which is a public string would give me the string that I inputted. Also, the children is a Map that gets the character String. And, the parameter checked if it is null or not already.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really enough information to go on, but I'll take a shot in the dark anyway

```
public static int longest(Node d) {
  if (d == null) return 0;
  else return Math.max(longest(d.left), longest(d.right)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: what If I can't call the d.left and right? Like the class only has a string and a boolean value??

Comment: @Sam - the problem with this whole question is that you are not expressing yourself clearly. For example, the term "digital tree" means nothing to me, and probably 99% of the people reading this.

Comment: @Sam, you cannot have a tree data structure in which you don't have a way for a node to point to child nodes.